# Use variable as role name ansible

Tags: linux, automation, ansible

I am beginner on ansible . i am creating a ansible-playbook . and i have created some variables like *dbengine* now i want to use this variable as a role name . my yml file as below .

```
---
 - hosts: examples
   remote_user: root
   become: yes
   become_method: sudo
   roles:
   - {{ dbengine }}
```

and my variable file is below.

```
############## DB Engine mysql/postgres/oracle
dbengine: "mysql"
dbuser: "root"
dbpass: "sample"
dbname: ""
####################################################
```

I want to make role name dynamic . Is it possible in ansible.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this syntax:

```
---
- hosts: examples
  roles:
    - role: "{{ dbengine }}"
```

Comment: It is throughing error  - ERROR! 'dbengine' is undefined